# Pass array in Laravel route to Blade template

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to pass an array of values from `routes.php` in Laravel to a `@foreach` loop in a Blade template. Here's my route routine:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $theColors = array("red","green","blue","yellow");
    return View::make('hello', array('theLocation' =>  'NYC', 'theWeather'=> 'stormy', 'theColors'));
});
```

And my Blade template code:

```
    @foreach ($theColors as $color)
    <p>The color is {{$color}}.</p>
    @endforeach
```

My log is showing that the variable in the template - `$theColors` - is not undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not passed `$theColors` correctly to the view

Change

```
return View::make('hello', array('theLocation' =>  'NYC', 'theWeather'=> 'stormy', 'theColors'));
```

to

```
return View::make('hello', array('theLocation' =>  'NYC', 'theWeather'=> 'stormy', 'theColors' => $theColors));
```

Comment: Perfect - I knew it was something basic I was missing. Thanks!